# Can't access pyFirmata from Processing.py

Tags: python, arduino, processing, firmata, pyprocessing

The following code produces an error message in the Processing IDE:

from pyfirmata import Arduino,util

"No module named pyfirmata"

I have no problem running the code directly in the python 2.7 interpreter.
But, I can't access the Processing API from the interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to place the library in question inside your sketch folder. Python Mode doesn't use your system python, and cannot see any of the modules installed there.